# Data transformation : bimodal feature

Tags: r, data-transformation, bimodal

I have a data feature that follows closely a bimodal distribution (mixture of two separate normal distributions with different mean, standard deviation and weights).

Is it meaningful to transform that feature in the 2 following features ?

1. A factor corresponding to one of the two the normal distributions
2. the distance to the mean of the selected normal distribution

**Here is an example :**

```
set.seed(122)

# fake bimodal data 
bimodal <- as.data.frame(
  c(rnorm(10000, mean=10, sd=5),
    rnorm(2000, mean=22, sd=2)))
names(bimodal) <- c("x")

ggplot(bimodal, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5)
```

[image: bimodal histogram]

**Estimating the mean and the boudary between the two normal distributions :**

```
densityCurve <- ggplot(bimodal, aes(x=x)) + geom_density()
densityCurveData <- ggplot_build(densityCurve)

localMax <- which(ggpmisc:::find_peaks(densityCurveData$data[[1]]$density) == TRUE)
localMax <- densityCurveData$data[[1]]$x[localMax]
    
localMins <- which(ggpmisc:::find_peaks(-densityCurveData$data[[1]]$density) == TRUE)
localMins <- densityCurveData$data[[1]]$x[localMins]
localMins <- c(-Inf, localMins, +Inf)

ggplot(bimodal, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 0.5) + geom_vline(xintercept = localMax, color="red", linetype="dashed") + geom_vline(xintercept = localMins, color="blue", linetype = "dashed") + geom_density(lwd=1, col="green", linetype = "dotted")
```

[image: Means and boundary]

**Data Transformation :**

```
bimodal$Mode <- cut(bimodal$x,
            breaks=localMins,
            right=TRUE)

returnMode <- function(modes, x) {
    distances <- sapply(modes, function(i) (x - i))
    distances[which(abs(distances) == min(abs(distances)))][1]
}

bimodal %<>% mutate(distToMode = sapply(x, returnMode, localMax))

ggplot(bimodal, aes(x=x, y=Mode)) + geom_jitter()
ggplot(bimodal, aes(x=distToMode)) + geom_density()
ggplot(bimodal, aes(x=distToMode)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image: Visualization of the two new features created]

**Test the normality of distToMode :**

```
shapiro.test(bimodal$distToMode[sample(5000)])
```

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  bimodal$distToMode[sample(5000)]
W = 0.9801, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Do you believe it's an efficient way to do?
Thanks,

## StayHome